# One-to-many relationship only one entry of the many needed

Tags: mysql, sql

At first, thank you for taking the time to read this

Problem:

Example

```
SELECT Article.ID, Article.Name, Article.Price, EV.EV, Pic.Upload_Datum 
FROM Article
LEFT JOIN Pic ON Articel.ID = Pic.Artikle_ID 
LEFT JOIN Stock ON Stock.ID = Article.Lager_ID
LEFT JOIN EV ON EV.ID = Article.EV_ID 
WHERE Article.Activ = "1" 
AND Stock.trader_ID = "2" 
AND Article.stock_ID = "1"
AND pic.Uploaddate IS NOT BETWEEN 1510903702 AND 1503127702
LIMIT 10
```

Example resutl

ID       Upload

2624919 1489736525

2624919 1489736528

2624920 1507295386

2624920 1507295389

2624920 1507295397

thats one of the results i get but i only need this two:

2624919 1489736525

2624920 1507295386

Now i get foreach Article.ID more than one record, because in the "pic" table there are more than one pictures of any article. The problem is, that i only need the first picture that the sql finds.

I hope its the right way to ask.

Greetings
B3rgi

Comment: How do you define "the first picture" ? If you have 10, in any order, which is the first one?

Comment: The first picture that it finds, the customer said that it doesnt matter which picture i take of the 10. So if there is for example footbool.png, duck.png and ball.png it doesnt matter which picture i take.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Do the min function on picture then and group by article fields

Comment: When i use the min function, wouldn´t it give me the lowest value of the whole table back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont really care of which data to take for your pic, see below sample, it will take the first pic of your Article.

```
SELECT Article.ID, Article.Name, Article.Price, EV.EV, 

         SELECT  Pic.Upload_Datum 
         FROM    Pic 
         WHERE   Articel.ID = Pic.Artikle_ID 
         LIMIT 1) AS Upload_Datum 
FROM Article
LEFT JOIN Stock ON Stock.ID = Article.Lager_ID
LEFT JOIN EV ON EV.ID = Article.EV_ID 
WHERE Article.Activ = "1" 
  AND Stock.trader_ID = "2" 
  AND Article.stock_ID = "1"
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP x` is MsSQL Server only. On MySQL you want `LIMIT x`

Comment: Thank you it works. But one question, can i use the Upload_Datum in the where? Like in the example AND pic.Uploaddate IS NOT BETWEEN 1510903702 AND 1503127702